How to fix DeltaLake Apache PyArrow TimeStamp conversion error in Python?
I am using DeltaLake's Rust library with Python bindings in order to query some data from an Azure Gen 2 Storage account however I am having problems with this specific error when trying to convert it to a Pandas dataframe or PyArrow table:
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns] to timestamp[us, tz=UTC] would lose data: -4852202631933722624

This only occurs when I try to query specific delta files, however after some reading apparently this issue is supposed to be fixed so I am not sure what is causing it. I tried to manually fix any broken timestamps with the following:
 dl = DeltaTable(...)

min_time = pd.Timestamp("2020-01-01")
max_time = pd.Timestamp("2025-01-01")
schema = dl.schema().to_pyarrow()
cols = []
for field in schema:
    if isinstance(field.type, pa.TimestampType):
        cols.append(field.name)

for col in cols:
    predicate_min = f"{col} < '{str(min_time)}'"
    new_values = {col: str(min_time)}
    dl.update(predicate=predicate_min, new_values=new_values)
    predicate_max = f"{col} > '{str(max_time)}'"
    new_values = {col: str(max_time)}
    dl.update(predicate=predicate_max, new_values=new_values)

return dl.to_pandas()

However it is simply too slow to be made usable, I am unable to perform data manipulation on any PyArrow Table or Pandas dataframe due to the fact that conversion requires some apparent time casting (as per my error). However conversion to PyArrow Dataset is successful but from there its quite limited into the type of manipulation I can try doing, such as creating a new schema.
This error only occurs when I try to perform the conversion into a tabular datatype, how can I fix this error or replace broken timestamps?

I have encouterd the similar ERROR:


ArrowInvalid: Casting from timestamp[ns, tz=UTC] to timestamp[us]
would lose data: 9223372036854775807

I have tried the below approach:
from delta import DeltaTable
delta_path = "/FileStore/tables/d01"
dl = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, delta_path)
df_spark = dl.toDF()
df_spark = df_spark.withColumn("timestamp", df_spark["timestamp"].cast("string"))
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()
print(df_pandas)

Results:
   id                   timestamp
0   1  1969-12-31 23:59:59.999999
1   2         1970-01-01 00:00:00
2   3  2262-04-11 23:47:16.854775

In the above code I am loading the Delta Lake table as a DeltaTable object.
Reading the DeltaTable as a PySpark DataFrame.
Converting the timestamp column to a string representation using the to_utc_timestamp function to preserve the precision.
Then convert the PySpark DataFrame to a Pandas DataFrame.

Unfortunately, I cannot use Spark sessions.
